# Contractible and open sets continuous mapping to $\mathbb C^*$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

If $U$ is contractible and open, and $f:U\to\mathbb C^*$ a continuous mapping (in my case $U$ is a subset of a smooth manifold, and $f$ is smooth), then is $f(U)$ contractible (or at least simply connected)? I want to define a function $\log\circ f:U\to\mathbb C$.

Comment: Every non-vanishing holomorphic function on an open simply connected domain of $\Bbb C$ has a continuous, hence holomorphic  logarithm. In particular, $V\ni z\longmapsto z\in V$, where $V$ is open simply connected domain of $C^*$.

Comment: What if $U=(0,1)\subset\mathbb R$, and $f:U\to\mathbb C^\times$ just wraps around the unit circle a few times?

Comment: So, if $\text{im}(f)\subseteq V$, then you can.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U=\big\{z\in\mathbb{S}^1 : 0<{\rm arg}(z)<\frac{3\pi}{2}\big\}\subseteq\mathbb{S}^1$, which is open in $\mathbb{S}^1$ and contractible (homeomorphic to an interval). Let $f(z)=z^3$. You have $f(U)=\mathbb{S}^1$.

Answer (score 1):

One counterexample to your claim that makes a helpful point is that $\exp: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ is a holomorphic (hence continuous) surjection, demonstrating the impossibility of your claim.

In general, any space $X$ that is not contractible but has a contractible universal cover will provide a counterexample for similar claims. Examples of these include $S^1$ (universal cover $\mathbb{R}$), all surfaces of non-positive Euler characteristic, or by Whitehead's theorem any path-connected CW complex $X$ with $\pi_1(X) \neq 0$ but $\pi_n(X) = 0$ for all $n > 1$.